# Java service sends the data, but in Angular, TypeScript components only one field from the returned object is populated

Tags: angular, typescript

This is the returned class, multiple Photo instances are returned:

```
export class Photo {
    id: string;
    photo: string;
    uploadtime: Date;
    restricted: boolean;
}
```

Service:

```
  public findByIds(idz: Number[]): Observable<Photo[]> {
    let paramz = new HttpParams();
    paramz= paramz.append('ids',idz.join(','));
    const newLocal = this.http.get<Photo[]>(this.photosUrl, {params: paramz});
    return newLocal;
  }
```

Component:

```
 photoz: Array<Photo>;

  listPhotz() {
    const idz=this.photoids.slice(this.counter,this.counter+10);
    this.photoService.findByIds(idz).subscribe(data => {this.photoz = data});
    this.counter=this.counter+10;
  }
```

HTML:

```
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let pht of photoz">
            <td><img [src]="photo" /></td>
            <td>{{ pht.id }}</td>
            <td>{{ pht.uploadTime }}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

But only the `pht.id` has values, others are empty. I've tested the rest service with curl, and the others are NOT empty.

BTW how can I photo (base64 string) appear as image in UI?
And why does not for example photoz have length (error, no length property, while google says arrays is ts should have it?

Comment: Only the second <td> is occupied with a value? As far as the last <td> goes, the value probably is not showing because of the camelcase "uploadTime". Your Photo model class has the property "uploadtime"

Comment: And your image is not showing because it should be `pht.photo`, not just `photo`, assuming `pht.photo` contains a URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The uploadtime propery probably is not showing because of the camelcase "uploadTime". Your Photo model class has the property "uploadtime"

How can you display an image base64 string? prepend it with data uri property:

```
this.imageUrl = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageBase64String;
```

Finally set it with angular data binding

```
<img src={{imageUrl}} />
```

Comment: thanks, that was one problem. BTW isn't there a useful angular development tool that listens for syntax, and mistype errors in html too?

As for images: i tried this, and something appears where the images should, but that's just the "broken" icon.

I've added the conversion to the constructor of Photo class:
  this.photo = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' +photo;

And in HTML: <td><img src={{pht.photo}} /></td>

Comment: and there are errors at browser console when i try to show images: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET 431 (Request Header Fields Too Large)

It seems that the this.photo remains unchanged... as if i plot the image as string, the base64 mime tipe is missing from the beginning. I don't understand this TS, i'm a simple java developer :(

Comment: now i made it working: i left the data as is, but in html i did this: <img src="{{'data:image/jpeg;base64,'+pht.photo}}" />
It works, but still not looks nice, and what if the photo is not jpg, but fe png.